# Clean (or maybe restructure/reshape) data in R (mainly about how to handle missing data)

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I encountered a problem when using R to clean a dataset.

The original dataset goes like the following:

```
ID  St  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6  Q7  Q8  Q9  Q10 gen ho  gu  qu
1   a   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   2   3   4   1   2   1   2
2   b   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   2   3   4   1   2
3   c   1   2   3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   2   1   2
4   d   1   NA  2   3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  3   4   1   2
5   e   1   2   3   4   5   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   2   1   2
6   f   NA  NA  NA  1   2   3   4   NA  NA  NA  3   4   1   2
```

I planed to reshape it to the following format (let's call it format1):

```
ID  St  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6  Q7  Q8  Q9  Q10 gen ho  gu  qu
1   a   1   2   3   4   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   2   1   2
2   b   1   2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  3   4   1   2
3   c   1   2   3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   2   1   2
4   d   1   2   3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  3   4   1   2
5   e   1   2   3   4   5   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   2   1   2
6   f   1   2   3   4   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  3   4   1   2
```

Or this one (format2, simply delete the columes in format1 containing all NA):

```
ID  St  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  gen ho  gu  qu
1   a   1   2   3   4   NA  1   2   1   2
2   b   1   2   NA  NA  NA  3   4   1   2
3   c   1   2   3   NA  NA  1   2   1   2
4   d   1   2   3   NA  NA  3   4   1   2
5   e   1   2   3   4   5   1   2   1   2
6   f   1   2   3   4   NA  3   4   1   2
```

Does anyone can help and teach me how to do the reshaping in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `apply` to loop over the rows of the 'Q' columns, append the non-NA elements with the NA elements, transpose the output and assign it to the columns of interest

```
nm1 <- grep("Q\\d+", names(df))
df[nm1] <- t(apply(df[nm1], 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))
df
#   ID St Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 Q8 Q9 Q10 gen ho gu qu
#1  1  a  1  2  3  4 NA NA NA NA NA  NA   1  2  1  2
#2  2  b  1  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA   3  4  1  2
#3  3  c  1  2  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA   1  2  1  2
#4  4  d  1  2  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA   3  4  1  2
#5  5  e  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA NA  NA   1  2  1  2
#6  6  f  1  2  3  4 NA NA NA NA NA  NA   3  4  1  2
```

Comment: if the numbers in Q1 to Q10 become string variables, such as "psychological department" rather than 1, do you know how to do it? I tried your method. It doesn't work out for the string variables...sad...

Comment: @vic If there is pattern in the column names, we can use `grep`.  But if your column names are `psychological deparment`, `wild fire`, `strawberries` which doesn't have any connection, it is better to use either `names(df1)[c(1, 3, 5)]` where 1, 3, 5, suggests the column index or just the column index to subset it

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain the question clearly. the column names are still Q1 to Q10, but the content changes from numbers to strings. Please see the example in this link:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h6fcQHb57_bpZ4jsozuNPWvS881VAJ2iY_Y5BSDrGKA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @vic  Yes, the procedure is the same except that you have to manually define the column names

Comment: Sorry about troubling you so many times today. I tried, but the problem is still there. The data structure is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h6fcQHb57_bpZ4jsozuNPWvS881VAJ2iY_Y5BSDrGKA/edit#gid=0. What I am trying to get is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D0aI37mqyUAS6pW4FwXobh0rw3_U9XrcSIOdxDtmMy4/edit?usp=sharing. I tried to modify your coding, but it didn't work. I guess it's due to that the type of Q1 to Q10 becomes "list" instead of "numeric". Do you know how to solve this problem. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @vic Not sure how you got a list there.  If the number of elements are the same, it should return `numeric`

Comment: problem solved. I found Excel is easier to do this. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort()` with the `na.last` option, applied to the respective columns.

Small working example:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:2, 
                 St = c("a","b"), 
                 Q1 = c(1,NA), 
                 Q2 = c(2, NA), 
                 Q3 = c(NA, 1), 
                 Q4 = c(NA, 2), 
                 gen = c(1,3))

df[,3:6] <- t(apply(df[,3:6], 1, function(x) sort(x, na.last = TRUE)))

   ID St Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 gen
1  1  a  1  2  NA NA   1
2  2  b  1  2  NA NA   3
```